# Android - fullscreen only in splash screen not in app

Tags: android, titlebar

I want to show my splash screen on fullscreen. I use this:

```
<activity android:name="app" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But when my splash screen finish, my app appear back of my status bar.

This is my `manifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
  package="com.maps" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"        
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="app" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
```

This is my `app.java` class:

```
public class app extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        //super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 5000);
    }
}
```

If I delete "fullscreen", the app show fine but the splash screen doesn fullscreen.

Comment: <Obligatory don't display a splash page comment /> its probably because your theme contains Theme.Black.NoTitleBar

Answer (score 10):

Add it in your splash activity or any activity you want to have fullscreen, just before your setContentView():

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: I add my manifest code melquiades, where i put your code? i use phonegap