# Enter full-screen during splash-screen activity

Tags: android, fullscreen, splash-screen, statusbar, navigationbar

I am currently trying to go full-screen during my splash-screen `Activity`. I am doing that with a `style`, which is set on the `Activity` like this:

style.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activities.SplashScreenActivity"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You might suggest doing that programmatically, but I already tried all the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823049/splash-screen-application-and-hide-action-bar), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459968/android-fullscreen-only-in-splash-screen-not-in-app), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompat), [this](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation), [this](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive) and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setSystemUiVisibility(int)) link. Currently, none of the programmatic solutions work for me - put every suggested fix in either `onResume` or `onCreate` of my `splashActivity.java`, but the status and navigation bar were still visible. However, when using my custom `style` it hides only the status bar, the navigation bar stays visible. What I've tried so far in the xml files: used different parents of the style, used no background drawable, removed `screenOrientation` and `noHistory` from `activity`. I am pretty sure I'm missing something here, but I can't see what. Can share more code if needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your SplashActivity extend from `AppCompatActivity` ?

Comment: Yes, it's extending AppCompatActivity: `public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Just to test, can you add this style to your application node in Manifest.xml:
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_new"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

Comment: I get a build error `Attribute application@theme value=(@style/MyMaterialTheme) from AndroidManifest.xml:33:9-43
   is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:33:9-43 value=(@style/SplashTheme).`

Comment: Are you defining `android:theme` two times in your application node?

Can you share your manifest.xml please?

Comment: I'm defining my application theme once, but some of my activities have different themes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173829/discussion-between-samyb-and-noterezeck).

Answer (score 1):

Here my SplashScreenActivity style:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_logo_drawable</item>
</style>
```

I only use the attribute `windowBackground`

Comment: This way my status bar hides, but the navigation bar is still visible.

Comment: Please share your splash activity layout

Comment: My splash activity has no layout. I only set a background of the style my activity use like you do, and the drawable looks like this: https://pastebin.com/96igp23U